# Hyperbolic space and metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, circles, hyperbolic-geometry

Using metrics is it possible to derive the circumference and area of a circle in hyperbolic space. I've found that the answer (without using metrics) are:
C=2πsinh(r)
and
A=4πsinh2(r/2).
But I'm unclear if this r represents the actual proper distance or the radius in hyperbolic space.

Comment: The points on a hyperbolic circle are of *varying* Euclidean distance (not "actual proper distance") from its hyperbolic center, so what's your guess? Also try and remember what you decided $r$ was when you first set out to calculate hyperbolic area or circumference. There's no way you could have done the calculation without knowing what $r$ stood for at some point.

Answer (score 0):

According to your formula, if $r$ is $1$, then $A$ is finite. But $r=1$ in Euclidean distance cover the whole unit disc. But the hyperbolic area of disc is infinite. For a simple idea of the proof  see [Here](http://www.maths.gla.ac.uk/wws/cabripages/hyperbolic/circleformulae.html).